HP-hp-envy x360 15-ew0022tx issue with audio
I have bought a new HP-hp-envy x360 15-ew0022tx and installed Ubuntu 24.04. Laptop speaker is not working on Ubuntu 24.04. The settings level shows that everything is fine. But audio is not coming from the Bang & Olufsen speaker. Tried different fixed. Is not working.
lspci -v
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 219, IOMMU group 17
Memory at 612d3c8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 612d200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
enter image description here
Please let me know any fixes.

I'm also facing the same issue currently. The headphones are sometimes detected but no audio output. I couldn't find any solution to it. However I have a workaround that does pretty well in my case. You can run the following command in the terminal and check if it works for you too,
$ sudo alsactl restore

After running the above command,the issue of no sound output was fixed almost instantly. I hope it works for you too.

Its not working. Its a new laptop.
